# Java regex allowing all character expect `

Tags: java, regex

I've created regex pattern to allow `count(*)` but not to allow `` `count(*)` ``

```
[^`]*[Cc][Oo][Uu][Nn][Tt][(](\*)[)][^`]*
```

It works out individually, but if I pass them together

```
count(*),`count(*)`
```

I should get this match but its opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `` [^`]* `` matches ***zero*** or more backticks, it does not thus prevents from matching a `Count(*)` string in between backticks.

You may use

```
(?i)(?<!`)Count\(\*\)(?!`)
```

Or, if you need to match it as a whole word, add `\b` at the start before the word:

```
(?i)(?<!`)\bCount\(\*\)(?!`)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K74avN/1)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive modifier
- `` (?<!`) `` - no  `` ` `` allowed immediately to the left of the current location.
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Count\(\*\)` - `Count(*)` substring
- `` (?!`) `` - no  `` ` `` allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

In Java,

```
String regex = "(?i)(?<!`)Count\\(\\*\\)(?!`)";
```

Comment: Pattern.matches for `count(*),\`count(*)\``  gives false

Comment: @aniket_777 Of course, `matches()` requires a full string match, use `find()` to find smaller matches in a longer string. What is the final goal? Extract or replace?

Comment: so that means my original pattern will also work with `find()` method. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @aniket_777 But your original regex does not restrict the `Count(*)` context. You need the lookarounds.

Comment: yes, but what if there is a space surrounded in backtick like `\`  count(*)  \`` It should not allow.

Comment: @aniket_777 Cool, since it is Java, you may use ``"(?i)(?<!`\\s{0,100})Count\\(\\*\\)(?!\\s*`)"`` if we can assume there can be no more than 100 whitespaces between the leading backtick and `Count(*)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211847/discussion-between-aniket-777-and-wiktor-stribizew).